# How to store a value on the exec in python

Tags: python

Hi I'm currently figuring out how to store the value of my input and putting it on the script that I use on python, on the script when I run it is usually "script.py filename.xlsx" because it reads a file before opening, now I am using the script as an Import, how can I use my old method when I call the script. This is my code

```
filename = input("Input XLSX file: ")
scriptrun = exec(open('script.py ', filename).read())
```

Comment: Arguments of `open` function are incorrect. Code does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You change your module script file to be importable, e.g. `module.py`:

```
def fn(filename):
    # load file etc
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    filename = input("INPUT XLSX file: ")
    fn(filename)
```

Then in your `application_script.py`:

```
   import module
   # obtain filename
   module.fn(filename)
```